# Change redirect to sign_in in Devise. I.e after "recover pass" form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need some advise with Devise :)) I have frontpage in my app, and i included a auth form in it. It works correct, but when system wants auth from me , it drops me in /users/sign_in. (i.e. after "pass recover"). What should i do to make my frontpage to be default page for sign_in ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the following:

```
# The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  new_session_path(resource_name)
end
```

if you extend `Devise::ConfirmationsController`. [Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) has a small section on configuring/extending Devise controllers.

Answer (score 0):

there are also multiple callbacks you can override :

## after successful sign up

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
end

## after successful sign in

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end